# How to construct a grouped boxplot including 6 groups ( expression levels of 6 different genes) and 2 subgroups (Control & Cancer) in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, melt

The data is similar to that indicated as below. It would greatly be appreciated if somebody can help me in this case.

Gene    Control expression    Cancer expression
BAX           12                    34
BID           18                     45
PMAIP1        10                     24
The graph should depict all the gene candidates in the x-axis and the expression level in the y-axis grouped by tumor and normal for each gene. The example has shown.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSaP8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your data does have the same formate as in my example, this code should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(value = rnorm(120, mean = 5),
                   genes = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), each = 20),
                   condition = rep(c("tumor", "normal"), times = 60))

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genes, y = value, fill = condition))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>